# iPhone/Android browser occasionally follows link href instead of jQuery onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iphone, browser

I have a mobile web gallery page where I have a CSS floated "next" link.  The CSS float property causes the link to have a display: block behavior on it.  A jQuery touchstart event is bound to the link.  When the user clicks on the link, the Javascript code bound to that touchstart event advances the gallery by one slide via Ajax. In other words, there is no page refresh.

However, I noticed that occasionally when I touch an area of the link's block space that is not the link text itself, the browser follows the href and causes a page refresh (because the URL has changed) instead of executing the Javascript code bound to the touchstart event.

Has anybody seen this before?  Is there a way to fix this?

I simplified it down to this code below, and it still happens, although much less frequently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

        <style type='text/css'>
            .cont { width: 320px; }
            .next { border-left: 1px solid #000; float: right; text-align: right; width: 65px; }
            .msg { clear: both; width: 200px; }
        </style>

        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
            $(function(){
                $('.next').bind('click touchstart', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();  
                    if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
                        $(this).unbind('click');
                    }                
                    $('.msg').append('<p>Click!</p>');                
                });
            });//]]>  
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cont"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="next">Next</a></div>
        <div class="msg"></div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on my iPhone and it seems to work. For some reason after registering a `touchstart` event you are unbinding the click events. Is there any reason for that?

When you click on the text of the link all it seems to register is indeed `touch start`, so unbinding `click` does not break things. I do believe, however, that when you touch outside the text link, but still within the block space it registers both a `touchstart` and `click`, so at this point you have already unbound `click` and it works as a regular link.

You should notice, that on your first click outside the bounds it never goes to yahoo.com. It's only the subsequent once that do that.

So in essence what you need to do is remove that `unbind`, as so:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(function(){
            $('.next').bind('click touchstart', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();            
                $('.msg').append('<p>Click!</p>');                
            });
        });//]]>  
    </script>
```

Is there any reason why you would want to unbind `click`?

Comment: I unbind the click event, because if I'm testing the page in a desktop browser, I want the click event to work normally.  Also, if I don't unbind the click event, the function runs twice: once for touchstart and once for click.

I got the idea of unbinding click events from Peter Paul Koch's presentation on mobile events:  http://www.slideshare.net/MobileConventionAmsterdam/peter-paul-koch-mobile-convention-amsterdam

Comment: But if you're running it in a desktop browser you will never do the unbind. It only happens if you have a `touchstart` event. Also when I was doing the testing I have not experienced the function running twice. So I think it should work.

You could also take a look at detecting supported events and registering different handlers if `touchstart` is supported. Take a look at http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/

If `touchstart` is supported you first disable `click` and than bind `touchstart` (the order matters). If not you just bind for `click`.

Comment: Maciek, thanks for the link. 

Sorry, my comment was messed up.  You are right.  I only unbind the click event for the mobile device, to prevent the function from running twice.  However, if you are not getting the same problem on the example I provided, then I need to examine my original code.  You've given me things to think about that I had not considered.  I'll comment here when I have more information about it.

Comment: Maciek, I used feature detect code to detect a touch device and the suppessed the click event.  Using both event.preventDefault() and return false in the click handler function, the problem I was seeing stopped.  You are right that the space between the text link and the box area of the link is a clickable area, but my click event handler (no longer unbound from the link) now stops it.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Hey, it's my first time doing web stuff on the iPhone so it was a learning experience on this side as well ;).